# Unable to pass value to JavaScript variable form a drop down form - Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript

I have an input form element in my HTML which passes a value to a function to initialize a game board. However I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" error.

Here is my form element:

```
<form>
    Difficulty<br>
    <select id="size">
        <option value='3'>Easy</option>
        <option value='4' selected>Normal</option>
        <option value='5'>Hard</option>
        <option value='6'>Extra Hard</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the corresponding JavaScript:

```
function initBoard() {
    var difficulty = document.querySelector('size').value
    var board = {}
    board.cells = []
    for (var i = 0; i < difficulty; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < difficulty; j++) {
            board.cells.push({ row: i, col: j, isMine: (Math.random() >= 0.7), isMarked: false, hidden: true })
        }
    }
    return board
}
```

I am stuck as to why the variable is null.

Comment: I have also tried it with document.getElementById('size').value

Comment: Use # in front of id. **document.querySelector('#size').value**

Answer (score 1):

Your `querySelector` is trying to refer to an id called size, so you need to refer to the CSS selector correctly (hash symbol):

```
var difficulty = document.querySelector('#size').value
```

The [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) on querySelector gives some examples of matching on different selector types.

Comment: You are correct about the query selector, thanks. However after changing the assignment to var difficulty = document.querySelector('#size').value I still get the same error message.

Comment: `alert(document.querySelector('#size').value)`
return the value, but for some reason the script function is recieving null.

Comment: Hmm.. I've dumped your code into a CodePen, and on its own, board seems to be returning fine out of your function. I've added a couple of console logs to it, so you can see its output, here: https://codepen.io/Cursa/pen/wvaPjyB?editors=1111
(make sure you open the console on the bottom left of the page to see the output)

Comment: Console seems to work and I am able to get the value in Dev Tools cosole, but still getting same error in my JavaScript.

Comment: That would suggest the problem lies outside of initBoard's code directly.. perhaps there's an issue in the order you're calling this/other functions; at the time of initBoard being called, it doens't sound like the DOM is ready to pass in its difficulty value.

Comment: I think you could be right. I have tried using selected index and all kinds of weird and wonderful ways to invoke the value of the id which work in Dev Tools but not in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code in `initBoard()` with:

```
var difficulty = document.getElementById("size");

var selectedValue=difficulty.options[difficulty.selectedIndex].text
```

Comment: Now
`var selectedValue = difficulty.options[difficulty.selectedIndex].text`
Gives the null error message.

Comment: Please make sure that you are hitting the initBoard() function.

Comment: It's fixed now. I created a new function called setDiffculty() called by the drop down-down onchange method, which then passed the value to InitBoard. I had to then initialize a new variable inside the setDiffculty() which called the InitBoard function  and that fixed it. However the script block was located at the top of my HTML document which was the issue because the DOM was not fully initialized when I was running the functions. Shifting the script block to the end of the body element  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now.

I created a new function called setDiffculty() called by the drop down-down onchange method, which then passed the value to InitBoard.

I had to then initialize a new variable inside the setDiffculty() which called the InitBoard function  and that fixed it.

However, the script block was located at the top of my HTML document which was the issue because the DOM was not fully initialized when I was running the functions. Shifting the script block to the end of the body element fixed the issue.

Thank you for your answers.